# Python 2.7 modules don't exists

Tags: python

Where can I find modules 'builtins' and 'future.backports.html'? I need these modules to run program at https://github.com/folz/cleverbot.py/blob/master/cleverbot/cleverbot.py

I tried to install these modules by 'pip' in cmd but cmd says that these modules don't exists.

Comment: only programming questions are available here...not for module installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [`setup.py`](https://github.com/folz/cleverbot.py/blob/master/setup.py) it says:

```
install_requires=['future', 'requests'],
```

So I would imagine that `pip install future` should do the trick:

```
$ pip install future
Downloading/unpacking future
  Downloading future-0.15.2.tar.gz (1.6MB): 1.6MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-Q_wkRy/future/setup.py) egg_info for package future
[..]
Successfully installed future
Cleaning up...
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from builtins import str
>>> from future.backports.html import parser
```

Not sure why you're not just running the `setup.py` file or using `pip`?